# When will the beta badges be awarded?

Tags: support, status-completed, badges

I noticed that the beta badges haven't been awarded yet on MA. According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66220/164138) beta badges are awarded shortly after a site goes to public beta. The martial arts site is public beta for almost a week now.
Did someone forget to award them, or are the badges now given at a later stage?

Comment: because big problems are big :)

Comment: @tacone I'm not saying it is a big problem, I was just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your missing beta badges have been found and granted to the respective parties.  ENJOY!

You can find the recipients [here](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta).